# Why are only 2 of my 5 tests running on my Google C++ testing framework

Tags: c++, googletest

This is the file

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <libLoam/c++/LoamStreams.h>
#include "../DateParser.h"

using namespace oblong::sluice;

TEST(DateParser, TestDefaultFormat)
{ DateParser parser;
  float64 when;
  EXPECT_EQ (OB_OK, parser . Parse ("12345.0", when));
  EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ (12345.0, when);
}

TEST(DateParser, TestYMDStuff)
{ DateParser parser;
  parser . AppendDateFormat ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
  float64 when;
  EXPECT_EQ (OB_OK, parser . Parse ("2011-11-14 19:12:21", when));
  const float64 expected = 1321297941.0;
  EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ (expected, when);
  EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ (0, when - expected);
} 

TEST(DateParser, TestJavaStringStuff)
{ DateParser parser;
  parser . AppendDateFormat ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
  float64 when;
  EXPECT_EQ (OB_OK, parser . Parse ("2011-09-18T09:49:47Z", when));
  const float64 expected = 1316339387.0;
  EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ (expected, when);
  EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ (0, when - expected);
}

TEST(DateParser, TestAM/PMStuff)
{ DateParser parser;
  parser . AppendDateFormat ("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S%p");
  float64 when;
  EXPECT_EQ (OB_OK, parser . Parse ("2011-11-14 10:12:21AM", when));
  const float64 expected = 1321265541.0;
  EXPECT_NEAR (when, expected, 1) << "Time should be close to expected " << (when - expected);
}

TEST(DateParser, TestTimeZoneStuff)
{ DateParser parser;
  parser . AppendDateFormat ("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S%Z");
  float64 when;
  EXPECT_EQ (OB_OK, parser . Parse ("2011-11-14 10:12:21GMT", when));
  const float64 expected = 1321265541.0;
  EXPECT_NEAR (when, expected, 1) << "Time should be close to expected " << (when - expected);
}

TEST(DateParser, TestOtherTimeZoneStuff)
{ DateParser parser;
  parser . AppendDateFormat ("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S%z");
  float64 when;
  EXPECT_EQ (OB_OK, parser . Parse ("2011-11-14 10:12:21+0900", when));
  const float64 expected = 1321297941.0;
  EXPECT_NEAR (when, expected, 1) << "Time should be close to expected " << (when - expected);
}
```

Yet when I try the test, It only executes the first 2 tests (TestDefaultFormat and TestYMDStuff). Whats worse, if I delete a test, then it will only test 1 (correct), yet if I add back in the deleted test, It doesn't test it anymore. So if I deleted TestYMDStuff, compiled it and ran it, it would only test the first one. Then if I added back in TestYMDStuff it still only runs the first one, let alone any new tests I added after that one.

What could this possible be??????? Is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH HA. the answer is, you can't have /'s in the titles of your tests. One of my tests was named  TestAM/PMStuff. Changing that to TestAMPMStuff fixed everything.